# Is it possible to quickly enable/disable a monitor in a dual monitor set-up (desktop)?

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, settings

I have a very simple set-up with only two screens and 3 very standard use cases:

[My set-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cr9on.png)

```
+------------------------+----------------+----------+
|         Set-up         | Screen (144Hz) |    TV    |
+------------------------+----------------+----------+
| A – joined or mirrored | Enabled        | Enabled  |
| B – Computer           | Enabled        | Disabled |
| C – Home Theater       | Disabled       | Enabled  |
+------------------------+----------------+----------+
```

Which means that when switching between set-ups I have these 4 scenarios:

```
+------- --------------------+-------------+-----------+
|       Scenarios            | From set-up | To set-up |
+----------------------------+-------------+-----------+
| 1 – Turn on TV             | B           | C         |
| 2 – Turn off TV            | C           | B         |
| 3 – Extend displays        | B/C         | A         |
| 4 – Back to single display | A           | B/C       |
+----------------------------+-------------+-----------+
```

I am aware that in Ubuntu I can use the default keyboard shortcut `super` + `p` to switch displays however it does not work in any of these scenarios.

In all of them I need to manually got into `settings` > `devices` > `display` and select what I want AND, every single time, re-increase the computer screen refresh rate from 60Hz to 144Hz.

Is there anyway to automate this?? On W10 you set it once and it remembers the set-up. You can then cycle through the set-ups (dual, single, projector, mirrored).

Here scenario 3 means repositioning the relative positions of the displays every time and scenario 4 cannot be achieved through the shortcut as my desktop does not have a 'built-in display'.

Alternatively is it possible to set an external display as the built in one?

Issues are:

1. If a screen is re-enabled, its settings are fully reset (resolution, refresh rate and relative position)
2. Without a built-in display, it is impossible to enable or disable a screen from the shortcut `super` + `p`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Credit to MestreLion for making this solution possible.**

Intense research later [I found a related question on SO with this great script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24933353/10645669):

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# monitor-switch - switch outputs using xrand
#
#    Copyright (C) 2012 Rodrigo Silva (MestreLion) <linux@rodrigosilva.com>
#
#    This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
#    it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
#    the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
#    (at your option) any later version.
#
#    This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
#    GNU General Public License for more details.
#
#    You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
#    along with this program. See <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

declare -A monitor_opts
declare -a monitors

myname="${0##*/}"
verbose=0

# Read settings from config file
config=${XDG_CONFIG_HOME:-"$HOME"/.config}/"$myname".conf
if [[ -f "$config" ]]; then
    source "$config"
fi

print_monitors() {
    while read -r output conn hex; do
        echo "# $output $conn   $(xxd -r -p <<<"$hex")"
    done < <(xrandr --prop | awk '
    !/^[ \t]/ {
        if (output && hex) print output, conn, hex
        output=$1
        hex=""
    }
    /ConnectorType:/ {conn=$2}
    /[:.]/ && h {
        sub(/.*000000fc00/, "", hex)
        hex = substr(hex, 0, 26) "0a"
        sub(/0a.*/, "", hex)
        h=0
    }
    h {sub(/[ \t]+/, ""); hex = hex $0}
    /EDID.*:/ {h=1}')
}

# if there's no pre-defined monitors list, read from xrandr
# and save them to config file
if [[ -z "$monitors" ]]; then
    while read -r output ; do
        monitors+=("$output")
    done < <(xrandr | awk '$2 ~/^c/{print $1}' | sort)
    cat > "$config" <<-EOF
        # $myname config file
        # List of monitors, from left to right. Edit to your actual layout
        monitors=(${monitors[@]})
        # Extra xrandr options for each monitor.
        # Useful when EDID data does not reflect actual preferred mode
        # Options for non-existing outputs (such as the examples below) are ignored
        # Examples:
        monitor_opts[DFPx]="--mode 1920x1080 --rate 60"
        monitor_opts[DFPy]="--mode 1280x720"
        # As a reference, these were the connected monitors when this config file was created
        # use it as a guide when editing the above monitors list and extra options
        $(print_monitors)
        # For an updated list, run $myname --list
    EOF
fi

message() { printf "%s\n" "$1" >&2 ; }
fatal()   { [[ "$1" ]] && message "$myname: error: $1" ; exit ${2:-1} ; }
argerr()  { printf "%s: %s\n" "$myname" "${1:-error}" >&2 ; usage 1 ; }
invalid() { argerr "invalid argument: $1" ; }
missing() { argerr "missing ${2:+$2 }operand${1:+ from $1}." ; }

usage() {
    cat <<-USAGE
    Usage: $myname [options]
    USAGE
    if [[ "$1" ]] ; then
        cat >&2 <<- USAGE
        Try '$myname --help' for more information.
        USAGE
        exit 1
    fi
    cat <<-USAGE
    Switch monitors using xrandr.
    Options:
      -h|--help          - show this page.
      -v|--verbose       - print in terminal the full xrandr command executed.
      -l|--list          - list connector and monitor names of connected outputs
      -a|--all           - enable all monitors.
      -s|--select OUTPUT - enable monitor OUTPUT, disable all others.
      -l|--left          - enable leftmost monitor.  Alias for --select ${monitors[0]}
      -r|--right         - enable rightmost monitor. Alias for --select ${monitors[${#monitors[@]}-1]}
    Copyright (C) 2012 Rodrigo Silva (MestreLion) <linux@rodrigosilva.com>
    License: GPLv3 or later. See <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
    USAGE
    exit 0
}

# Option handling
for arg in "$@"; do [[ "$arg" == "-h" || "$arg" == "--help" ]] && usage ; done
while (( $# )); do
    case "$1" in
    -v|--verbose) verbose=1 ;;
    -q|--no-notify) notify=0 ;;
    -l|--list) list=1 ;;
    -a|--all) all=1 ;;
    -s|--select) shift ; monitor="$1" ;;
    -l|--left ) monitor="${monitors[0]}" ;;
    -r|--right) monitor="${monitors[${#monitors[@]}-1]}" ;;
    *) invalid "$1" ;;
    esac
    shift
done

if ((list)); then
    echo "Connected monitors:"
    print_monitors
    exit
fi

if [[ -z "$monitor" && -z "$all" ]]; then
    usage
fi

# Loop outputs (monitors)
for output in "${monitors[@]}"; do
    if ((all)) || [[ "$output" = "$monitor" ]]; then
        xrandropts+=(--output "$output" --auto ${monitor_opts["$output"]})
        if ((all)); then
            if [[ "$output" = "${monitors[0]}" ]]; then
                xrandropts+=(--pos 0x0 --primary)
            else
                xrandropts+=(--right-of "$previous")
            fi
            previous="$output"
        else
            xrandropts+=(--primary)
        fi
    else
        xrandropts+=(--output "$output" --off)
    fi
done

((verbose)) && message "$myname: executing xrandr ${xrandropts[*]}"
xrandr "${xrandropts[@]}"
```

The code is also shared on [Github](https://github.com/MestreLion/scripts/blob/master/monitor-switch).

With this script mapped to a keyboard shortcut I can easily switch monitors:

```
monitor-switch --left
monitor-switch --right
```

The script also creates a configuration file in `/home/.config/monitor-switch.conf`. This 3 lines config file allow for two things to be registered:

1. The physical layout of the screens: which one is on the left/right of the other. Which is great when your main display is on the right of your secondary display (my case).
2. The mode to use when a monitor is turned on (default being `xrandr --auto`). In mine for instance I can save `monitor_opts[DP-2]="--mode 1920x1080 --rate 144"`

Comment: Tested on 20.0.4 and does its job . But to preserve the order of the monitors you have to edit ~ /.config/monitor-switch.conf
example:
monitors=(eDP-1 DP-1)
I had to invert the default that was (DP-1 eDP-1)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes my monitors will go out of alignment (left becomes right, top becomes bottom, etc.) and sometimes my second monitor will get washed out colours. For this I simply type `xreset` and all goes back to normal. I created a function in `~/.bashrc` for this purpose:

```bash
$ type -a xreset

xreset is a function

xreset () 
{ 
    # Reset xrandr to normal, first use: xrandr | grep " connected "
    # HDMI-0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1107mm x 623mm
    # eDP-1-1 connected primary 1920x1080+3840+2160 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 382mm x 215mm
    # DP-1-1 connected 3840x2160+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1600mm x 900mm
    xrandr --output HDMI-0  --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0       --rotate normal \
           --output eDP-1-1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 3840x2160 --rotate normal \
           --output DP-1-1  --mode 3840x2160 --pos 1920x0    --rotate normal

}
```

You could do something similar with `xconfig1`, `xconfig2`, etc and then bind them to short cut keys.

Comment: Thank you, going for a script + binding them to keys was the solution that I ended up going with. I took the script from MestreLion as it reads + parse the edid info to detect the monitors.